# Compatibility of predictive steering hub with boost 110 fork

Tags: hub, compatibility, boost, boost-spacing

I have a bike which had a RS1 fork and a wheel with a required predictive steering hub.

I have a second bike which has a Boost 110 front fork.

Since both these hubs are 110mm wide, can I use the wheel with the predictive steering hub on the Boost 110 fork?

I know it does not work the other way around since the RS1 fork does require the predictive hub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to SRAM's website, the Predictive steering hubs use a "dedicated interface for the RS-1 fork".

The hub/dropout interface is toothed, to lock the dropout and hub into place and prevent twisting.

Boost 110:

[image]

Predictive Steering hub:

[image]

In addition, the Maxle Ultimate which is designed for the RS-1 and is required on the hubs, is only available for the RS-1 and some recent model year Pike forks.

It is unlikely that the predictive steering hub is compatible with the standard Boost 110 spec.

Comment: No problem. Sorry it's probably not what you wanted to hear. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a PS hub on a Boost fork but there is a couple things you need to know.

1. The brake rotor mount on a Boost is 10.5mm from the brake side end cap while the PS is 12.5mm. So you will need 2mm worth of rotor spacers on the PS hub so the brake rotor doesn't rub.
2. The Boost fork must be able to accept 28mm Torque Caps(Rock Shox). The PS hub end caps are toothed and will gouge the paint but it is more secure.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Heith. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site. Nice first answer

Answer (score 0):

31 or even 32 mm for the Torque caps. So the fork has to be reworked accordingly which is not always so easy but possible