# Can I use Rockshox RS1 with Mavic 15X110?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels

can I use a Rock Shox RS-1 suspension with Mavic Crossmax Pro Carbon boost 15X110 wheel?

Comment: are your RS-1 boost spaced ? . Are your RS-1 the right size for your wheel diameter. If so then probably yes.

Comment: Or likely no , the RS-1 seems to have a proprietary SRAM hub.

Comment: I don't have the wheels yet, the RS1 only comes with the 110X15 axle, so I would like to know if the Mavic wheel fits. The sellers give this measure, but do not say whether it serves this suspension. I wonder if anyone has used both parts together.

Comment: https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/components/forks/suspension-forks/rockshox-rs-1-review/ claims the shock needs the proprietary hub to be stiff enough yet other forum people https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=150239 say you can use any 15x110 hub - YMMV

Answer (score 1):

The RS-1 is supposed to be used with a predictive steering hub, which has special teeth to engage with the fork - a standard boost hub will not have these.

You can see more details in this answer from zenbike:
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/39048/14027